# How to Parse XML in PHP with simplexmlelement?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to pharse an xml file in php using simplexmlelement.

```
 <OrderResponse>
      <OrderResponseReferences>
           <BuyersOrderNumber Preserve="true">100000002</BuyersOrderNumber>
           <SuppliersOrderReference Preserve="true">6711637</SuppliersOrderReference>
      </OrderResponseReferences>
 </OrderResponse>
```

I am using the code below to access BuyersOrderNumber

```
$local_file_path = "C:/etrade_files/Orders/order_acknowledgements/ORA1707220-05-2015--16-48-31.xml";
        
$xml = simplexml_load_file($local_file_path);
        
foreach($xml->children() as $child) 
{
    $child = $child->getName();
            
    if($child == "OrderResponseReferences")
    {
        $order_reference = $xml->$child->BuyersOrderNumber;
                
        print_r($order_reference);
    }   
}
```

Result:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Preserve] => true ) [0] => 100000002 )
```

How can I just get the order number which is **100000002**

Also this files have multiple order lines it would really help me if someone can explain the logic I can use to get all the required information.

```
 <OrderResponseLine>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <OrderResponseLineReferences>
           <BuyersOrderLineReference Preserve="true">100000002</BuyersOrderLineReference>
      </OrderResponseLineReferences>
      <Product>
           <SuppliersProductCode>108696</SuppliersProductCode>
      </Product>
      <Quantity>
           <Amount>2</Amount>
      </Quantity>
      <LineTotal>331.18</LineTotal>
 </OrderResponseLine>
```

Comment: there's no `<BuyersOrderNumber>` in your second XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cast the object to a string, it'll use its value and convert that:

```
print_r((string) $order_reference);
// 100000002
```

I tried your code and you're doing well! Just the `(string)` should be enough to get the script running.

Comment: Thank you. Would be able to help me the other part please. There are multiple <OrderResponseLine> within the file I do not understand how can I loop through each one and get the information I need.

Comment: You can actually always do `foreach ($someParentNode as $someChildNode) { ... }` to loop through simplexml objects, so you just have to find the location of the lines and foreach them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use DOM in order to parse this XML.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('ORA1707220-05-2015--16-48-31.xml');
$root = $xml->getElementsByTagName('OrderResponse');
$tree = $root->item(0);
$child = $tree->childNodes;
foreach($child as $children){
    switch($children->nodeName){
         case 'OrderResponseReferences':
             //instructions
    }
}
```

And use `nodeValue` to get value of the node.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to use this but when I do $children->nodeValue it is getting values for all the nodes within <OrderResponseReferences>. I tired to do something like $children->BuyersOrderNumber->nodeValue but this is giving me error. How can I get the value for specific nodes separately.

Comment: If I understand, you want to get only 'BuyersOrderNumber' value. I think a good solution could be a recursive function. If you you wanna get the child->child->value, like BuyersOrderNumber, tell me, and I'll post a code with an answer which seems me correct

Comment: Yes that is what I need as I also have multiple order line within this file but I only need to get specific values. I have always wanted to learn DOM thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**DOMDocument** and *recursive* function seems me working to get this value.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('ORA1707220-05-2015--16-48-31.xml');
$root = $xml->getElementsByTagName('OrderResponse');
$tree = $root->item(0);

parse($tree);

function parse($tree){
    $child = $tree->childNodes;

    foreach($child as $children){
        switch($children->nodeName){
             //Case
                 //instructions
        }


        if($child->hasChildNodes())
            parse($child);
        }

 }
```

If there's subnodes in the current node, it will call parse() again on the child, and you'll get the value yu want

Comment: Thank you I will try to use this login in my script now.

Comment: Hope it will useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are **much easier ways**:

**retrieve many `<BuyersOrderNumber>`:**

use `xpath`:

```
$numbers = $xml->xpath("//BuyersOrderNumber");
```

Explanation:

- the `xpath` statement will select any `<BuyersOrderNumber>`
- anywhere in the XML tree (due to the `//` in front of the node name)
- `$numbers` will hold an array of `SimpleXML` elements

Output all nodes:

```
foreach ($numbers as $n)
    echo $n;
```

**retrieve one single `<BuyersOrderNumber>` node**

1. the standard way:
   if there is only one such node in the XML:

   ```
   echo $xml->OrderResponseReferences->BuyersOrderNumber;
   ```
2. again `xpath`:

   ```
   echo $xml->xpath("//BuyersOrderNumber")[0];
   ```

   get all nodes and echo the first one only (that's why the `[0]`)

see a working example: https://eval.in/368739

Of course, `$xml` in the examples is..

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($local_file_path);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php